# Angular Material Theme does not change the mat-dialog accent color

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I need to change the colors theme of my app according to a parameter and it should be a very simple operation. In my app I use a Fuse angular material theme. When I try to switch from the primary to the secondary theme, the accent color of the dialog component does not change while the other components (for example the navigation bar) do.

_theme.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@import './component-themes';

$primary: mat-palette($mat-fusedark);
$accent: mat-palette($mat-light-blue, 600, 400, 700);
$warn: mat-palette($mat-red);
$white: mat-palette($mat-white);
$black: mat-palette($mat-black);

$first-theme: mat-light-theme($primary, $accent, $warn);

$background: map-get($first-theme, background);
$foreground: map-get($first-theme, foreground);

@include angular-material-theme($first-theme);
@include component-themes($first-theme);

$second-primary: mat-palette($mat-fusedark);
$second-accent: mat-palette($mat-green, 600, 400, 700);
$second-warn: mat-palette($mat-red);

$second-theme: mat-light-theme($second-primary, $second-accent, $second-warn);

.second-theme {
  @include angular-material-theme($second-theme);
  @include component-themes($second-theme);
}
```

component-theme.scss

```
@import "../partials/navigation";
@import "../partials/dialog";

@mixin component-themes($theme) {
  @include navigation-theme($theme);
  @include dialog-theme($theme);
}
```

_dialog.scss

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

    @mixin dialog-theme($theme) {
      $accent: map-get($theme, accent);
    
      .dialog-wrapper {
        .mat-dialog-container {
          padding: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
    
        .mat-dialog-title {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
          justify-content: space-between;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 24px;
    
        }
    
        .mat-toolbar {
          background-color: mat-color($accent) !important;
        }
    
        .mat-dialog-content {
          padding: 16px 32px 0px;
          margin: 0;
        }
    
        .mat-dialog-actions {
          display: flex;
          flex: 1 1 auto;
          margin: 1px 0 0 0;
          padding: 0px 32px 16px;
        }
    
      }
    }
```

If I change in the _dialog.scss the value

```
background-color: mat-color($accent) !important;
```

into

```
background-color: green !important;
```

it works properly. It looks like `mat-color($accent)`does not work but only for the scss of this component.

Answer (score 5):

For who runs into this problem, I have finally found a solution. I could not change the theme of some components because they are nested and the overlay container blocks the theme propagation. In order to fix it, I imported the overlayContainer and add the theme class into the overlayContainer in the ngOnInit method.

```js
import {OverlayContainer} from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

constructor(
    private overlayContainer: OverlayContainer
  ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    if (this.data.theme === 'second-theme') {
          this.overlayContainer.getContainerElement().classList.add(this.data.theme);
        }
}
```

Very easy solution when you know what is the problem, the hard part was to find it out :)

Comment: I set the them for my angular app and I am facing the same problem. I havent specified the name of the theme so what className should I use? I have used a syntax `$theme: mat.define-light-theme(options here)` though.